# Generate phone number goes slow c#

Tags: c#

My project is about generating phone numbers, but it goes very slow, is there any way to make it faster?

My code:

```
Int64 number = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);
do
{
    for (Int64 i = number; i < Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text); i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox3.Text + i);
    }
} while (number == Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text));

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox3.Text+textBox2.Text);
```

The textbox2 always contain 10 numbers same as textbox3

Comment: instead of directly add rows to the DGV, create a list and bind it to the DGV

Comment: Also don't do this all the time `Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text)` convert it once, and definitely don't use it in a condition for whiles or for loops

Comment: Also name you your Textboxes with intuitive names while you are at it

Comment: Also use `TryParse` instead of convert and validate the input

Comment: Actually, just start all over again i think

Comment: @TheGeneral what leaves me wondering is the big old while loop around the whole thing.  I mean, if `number` is the same as `textBox2.Text` it's going to loop forever, but the for loop will never run.

Comment: @john yeah that while loop is a goody, its definitely a case of, delete make a coffee think about it some more and start from scratch

Comment: To be honest, the code is way to complicated in accord what it does. My advice referring to TheGeneral: Start all over again and make sure you only parse each textbox once. Furthermore use the loops a bit more carefully

Comment: Generate the numbers only when the grid needs them.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control

Answer (score 0):

If you want it faster parse all the conversions first, iterate the values on actual numbers, then add them to the text at the end in a lump as one string.

The code doesn't make sense to me but to make what you have work this will be much faster...

```
Int64 number1 = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);
Int64 number2 = Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text);
do
{
    for (Int64 i = number1; i < number2; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox3.Text + i);
    }
} while (number1 == number2);

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox3.Text + textBox2.Text);
```